# VScode font sizes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VScode but unable to set a particular font size/text size for various areas of my VScode display.

For ex- in the image below the font size of python code is very big but the font size of the output is super tiny for my notebook. How can I adjust both the font sizes please?

I have tried adjusting various font sizes but it seems to mess everything up

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 22H2
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: VScode Version: 1.86.2 (system setup)

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: Unfortunately , no. I am still struggling